# Is it possible to have Django custom template tags load other templates in package

Tags: python, django

What I'm looking to do is package templates in a Django package which can be inserted on a developers page by simply using

```
{% load app_tags %}
```

this works find for custom methods which take a value and return a value.  What I would like to do is simply have a method which returns a template packaged with the app.

```
{{ custom_template }}
```

So the question boils down to how do I have a project which installs my app load my apps' tags and call a tag method which includes a template from the app.

thank you for any responses.

Comment: the interesting part is how to include a template packaged in the app_tags, i think your app_tags should use the tag method @register.inclusion_tag(template_packaged_name) and now your template_packaged_name going to include {{custom_template}}.

Comment: Thanks drabo2005 I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup!  make an inclusion tag in app_tags.py, and then call it!

they're great for code reuse  (along with Django blocks and the {% include ... %} template tag, of course)

reference:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

```
# app_tags.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("templates/myappname/greeting.html")
def greet(name, end="!!!"):
     return { 'name': name,  'end': end }
```

and

```
 {# templates/myappname/greeting.html  #}

 <h1>  What's up {{ name }}{{ end }}  </h1>
```

then to call this, you'd use `{%` and `%}`,    the double bracket notation e.g. {{ custom_template }} is really only for showing the value of a single variable

```
{% load app_tags %}

{% for person in people_to_greet %}
     {% greet person %}
{% end %}

<h3> cool greetings above ^ </h3>
```

Comment: Thanks David! awesome answer.  I completely missed that in the documentation.